# c++ malloc for array in struct

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, struct

I'm a java programming who is attempting to learn some c++ but I'm still a bit unsure of the interaction of arrays malloc and structs. I have the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct MapData
{
    double heights[];
    int width; 
};

void Map(int xsize,int ysize)
{
    MapData md;
    md.width=xsize;
    md.heights=malloc(sizeof(int)*xsize*ysize);
}
```

The idea beeing that I can now store data inside this MapData struct for later use. However this doesn't work as "incompatible types void* could not be assigned to double[0] . I know it's probably something stupid but I have tried a few things and I think it should work. Do I need to install something to get malloc or is using malloc to allocate a array just not the way to do thing in c++ (I have writen a small program before in c which used malloc for something like this but I can't quite remember/find the code for that one).

Comment: The function is called `malloc`.

Comment: it is `malloc`, not `mallock`, also you have a function which is called Map, not a member function, because you end the struct after `int width; };` because of the second semicolon. Put the `};` after the Map. Map is constructor, which is not allowed to have return type specification(you only write `Map(int xsize, int ysize)` without void

Comment: Please, for the love of god, use the appropriate headers `<cstdlib>` and `<cstdio>`. Also, if you really want to learn **c++** use `new` not `malloc`

Comment: @CoffeeandCode also `std::vector` instead of plain-old dynamically allocated arrays.

Comment: @NikBougalis especially for a beginner!

Comment: This function leaks memory too, since `md` only exists for the lifetime of the function and you never free the memory. I think you meant to operate on `width` and `height` , and do away with `md` completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ version of what you are trying is:

**Update:** OP clarified requirements, it is logically a 2-D array being stored in a 1-D vector (which is fine, I prefer this to using a vector of vectors)

```
#include <vector>

struct MapData
{
    int width;
    std::vector<double> cells;

    double &cell(int x, int y)
    {
        return cells.at(y * width + x);
    }

    MapData(int xsize, int ysize)  // the constructor
        : width(xsize), cells(ysize*xsize)
    { }
};
```

Because your class only contains "nice" types,its default behaviour on copy, move, and assignment, is correct.

Usage:

```
int main()
{
    MapData my_data(5, 6);
    my_data.cell(0, 3) = 1.1; 
}
```

Notes: I swapped the order of the elements so that the initialization list order matches the actual initialization order (initialization happens in the order of elements in the class, not the order of the init list).

Consider making `cells` and `width` private to avoid users of the map accidentally accessing them directly.

Comment: That works thank you one thing through is that heights was origenally xsize*ysize (trying to put a 2d array into a 1d array/vector);

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for a dynamically-allocated array. In C++ this is `std::vector<>`. So you should declare `heights` like this:

```
std::vector<double> heights;
```

And you can add items with `heights.push_back(1.5);`. You can also set the size in one shot with `heights.resize(...)`

See documentation at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

`malloc` is discouraged in C++ because it has no type-safety, is incompatible with non-POD types, and has no inherent protection against memory leaks.

You can get the type-friendliness with `new[]`, e.g. `double* heights; ... heights = new double[n]; ... delete [] heights;`), but this still has no memory leak protection.

`std::vector` is the superior choice.

Answer (score 0):

There are some differences in how you handle this in C or C++. You will have to choose one.

In C you need `malloc` and family. Please make sure to actually use a C compiler, not a C++ one.

```
double (*my_array)[ysize]; // Pointer to your new two-dimenasional array with column size ysize
my_array = calloc(sizeof(double), xsize*ysize); // allocates memory, implicit cast is invalid in C++

// use
my_array[x][y];

// free memory after use
free(my_array);
```

In C++ it's slightly different. The way similar to C is to use `new`, sadly in C++ it does not support variable length arrays:

```
double * my_array = new double[xsize*ysize];

// use
my_array[x * ysize + y];

// free
delete my_array;
```

This usage works, but is discouraged in C++ and it is recommended to use the `vector` class instead which behaves just like Java's `ArrayList`

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> my_array; // auto-initialised

// use
my_array[x][y];

// no need to free, it is removed automatically by the destructor for vector
```